# nginx 301 contains internal address

Tags: redirect, nginx

I use two Docker containers to host my application. The first container contains nginx listening port 80. This is an "entry point" to my application and currently it only passes all requests to container 2 (my-app). The nginx configuration is the following:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;

events {
        worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include    mime.types;

    server {
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://my-app:80;
        }
    }
}
```

The second container's nginx configuration looks like this:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;

events {
        worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include    mime.types;

    server {

        root /var/www/my-app/public;

        location = / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:81;
        }

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html @backend;
        }

        location @backend {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:81;
        }
}
```

}

The problem is: when nginx wants to automatically re-route the client to a new address, it correctly returns 301 but the location header incorrectly contains an internal address.

For example: If I go to http://localhost:80/my-folder, the request first goes to the container 1, which passes it to container 2, which then returns 301 asking the browser to go to the new location which is incorrectly the following:
http://my-app/my-folder/

The correct location should contain the originally asked host: http://localhost/my-folder/

And of course in production, the address example.com/my-folder should be forwarded to example.com/my-folder/, instead of my-app/my-folder/

**Why is nginx re-routing the client using internal address? How can I solve this problem?**

Comment: You can place `server_name .example.com;` inside the `server` section of your config. You can also try putting `proxy_set_header Host $host;` (try also `Host my-app;`) inside the `location @backend;` section. And make sure your backend is sending proper 301 redirects, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to set certain redirect headers correctly. I also found a full tutorial to do this:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/docker-explained-how-to-containerize-and-use-nginx-as-a-proxy

Also, thanks to Ivo Gelov for helping me move to the right direction. :)